# SUM YTD sales but only until last month

Tags: powerbi, dax

Can somebody please help me: I am trying to SUM YTD sales but only until last month.

Today= 23.02.2023

The following formula sums up YTD sales until today (23.02.2023). However, I want to sum only until last month (31.01.2023).

```
Net Sales YTD = TOTALYTD( SUM('SAP'[Net sales]), year'Date'[Masterdate] )
```

.... here I want to exclude: PREVIOUSMONTH('Date'[Masterdate]))

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure:

```
YTD = 
VAR startDate = 
    DATE( YEAR(TODAY()) - 1, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY()))
VAR endDate = 
    DATE( YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1)
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[Value]),
        startDate <= 'Table'[Date] && 'Table'[Date] < endDate
    )
```

Comment: Dear Peter 

Thank you very much for your appraciated support!!! 

I tried to apply the formula.... however the calculated YTD sales are 10x higher as expectced. 

I think a there is a small mistake in the definition of the start date / end date 

YTD = 
VAR startDate = 
    DATE( YEAR(TODAY())-1 , MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY()))
VAR endDate = 
    DATE( YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1)
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('SAP'[Net sales]),
        startDate <= 'Date'[Masterdate] && 'Date'[Masterdate] < endDate
    )

Comment: Did that answer the question or is something still missing?